# Django Model, Forms Fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am struggling with django forms.
I have been created model.form that its IntegerField but django takes them as string.

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class CircuitComponents(models.Model):
    e1 = models.IntegerField()
    r1 = models.IntegerField()
    c1 = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import CircuitComponents


class CircuitComponentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CircuitComponents
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import CircuitComponentForm


def circuit_components_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CircuitComponentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CircuitComponentForm()

    e1 = request.POST.get('e1')
    c1 = request.POST.get('c1')
    r1 = request.POST.get('r1')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'basic_circuit_result': e1 + c1 + r1
    }
    return render(request, 'basic_circuit.html', context)
```

There is also ss from the application. I was trying to make summing up them but result is as you can see on ss..
Can anyone help me with the thing that i am not seeing :D ? thanks in advance..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpwCA.png)

Comment: `request.POST` will take everything as a string. It is the form that converts it to a value accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` will take everything as a string, the POST parameters are always key-value pairs where both the keys and the values are strings. It is the form that converts it to a value accordingly.

You can use the [**`.cleaned_data`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) to get the values that are determined by the form, so:

```
def circuit_components_view(request):
    basic_circuit_result = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CircuitComponentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            basic_circuit_result = form.cleaned_data['e1'] + form..cleaned_data['e1'] + form..cleaned_data['r1']
            
    else:
        form = CircuitComponentForm()
    
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'basic_circuit_result': basic_circuit_result
    }
    return render(request, 'basic_circuit.html', context)
```

Comment: then i have problem when i am refreshing the page, that exactly throwing ``local variable 'basic_circuit_result' referenced before assignment `` that error.

Comment: @kozmonotosman: that is why you write `basic_circuit_result = None` at the top of the view.